# Running into delta.exceptions.ConcurrentAppendException even after setting up S3 Multi-Cluster Writes environment via S3 Dynamo DB LogStore

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, delta-lake

My use-case is to process a dataset worth 100s of partitions in concurrency. The data is partitioned, and they are disjointed. I was facing `ConcurrentAppendException` due to S3 not supporting the “put-if-absent” consistency guarantee.

From Delta Lake 1.2, with the help of S3DynamoDBLogStore API, all writers across multiple clusters and/or Spark drivers can concurrently write to Delta Lake S3 while ensuring that only one writer succeeds with each transaction. My Delta Lake version is 2.1.

I created a Dynamo DB table with auto-scaling enabled for number of reads/writes and passed the configuration to the delta job.

**Please find the configuration below (omitted some spark related config).**

```py
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Delta Operations") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", args["spark_driver_memory"]) \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", args["spark_executor_memory"]) \
        .config("spark.io.delta.storage.S3DynamoDBLogStore.ddb.tableName", args["log_table_name"]) \
        .config("spark.io.delta.storage.S3DynamoDBLogStore.ddb.region", args["log_region"]) \
        .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')
```

**Please find the actual logic below:**

```py
delta_table.alias("old").merge(
    input_df.alias("new"),
    f"old.{primary_key} = new.{primary_key}"
)
    .whenMatchedDelete(condition=col(f"old.{primary_key}").isin(deletes_df)) \
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
    .execute()
```

`delta_table` is the destination table in delta lake.

`input_df` is a combined data frame of all the inserts, and updates.

`deletes_df` is the dataframe that has just the deletes.

I am still running into **delta.exceptions.ConcurrentAppendException** irrespective of these settings. Am I doing something wrong?